# Combining multiple tables in rails it is taking too much time to get the records? How to increase performance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my model i am applying multiple methods and finally getting data as projects.

```
Project.active_leads(filter_params).city_id(filter_params).date_range(filter_params)
```

Comment: What does your console tell you? What does your code look like?

Comment: In project model I am joining 3 tables. After running the queries it is taking too much time to display the data in my views

Comment: Would you share us the code of `active_leads` ?

Comment: Is the problem with the query? Or with the rendering? In your title, you say "it is taking too much time to get the records." This implies a query problem. In your comment you say, "After running the queries it is taking to much time to display the data in my views." This implies a rendering problem. So, which is it?

Comment: It is query problem only because of queries rendering is slow.

Comment: If you say so. Good luck with all of that.

Comment: In active_leads class methods I am adding joins(:leads). where("leads. active=?",filter_params)

Comment: Please post the code of the scope in play, your view, your database structure including indexes and the log for one request to the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to make it as Scopes and cache it through Redis